# Modular Arithmetic and Divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can one determine if $$28 | 89^{135} $$

Comment: Can an even number divide an odd number?

Comment: Note also that $89$ is prime.

Answer (score 1):

The parity argument is enough for yes/no answer, so to get a more detailed answer:

$89^{135}\equiv 5^{135} \bmod 28$, and since [$\lambda(28)=6$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), and $5,28$ are coprime, $5^6\equiv 1 \bmod 28$. Thus $89^{135}\equiv 5^{135}\equiv 5^3\equiv 13 \bmod 28$.

$89^{135}$ has a remainder of $13$ when divided by $28$.

Comment: It would help to explicitly mention that you are (intentionally?) doing much more than needed, since a trivial parity argument proves indivisibility.

Answer (score 0):

Last digit of $89^{135}$ = last digit of $9^{135}$ = last digit of $1^{67} \times 9= 9$

i.e., $89^{135}$ is an odd number as mentioned in @egreg in his comment.

So, it is obvious that $89^{135} \not\equiv 0 \pmod {28}$ because $28$ is even

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Last digit of $89^1 = 9$

Last digit of $89^2 = 1$

Last digit of $89^3 = 9$

Last digit of $89^4 = 1$

Do you see a pattern here? The numbers cycle from $9,1,9,1$ and so on. So now consider your case, which is $89^{135}$. Can you take it from here?